# Can I ask about my chances in maths career or will I get flagged?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I've been thinking lately how good chances I have to achieve my goals as a mathematics researcher. I need someone who have enough experience in the field. I'm not sure tough, if Mathematics SE is the right place to do so without getting flagged.

And if the question is off-topic, where could I ask it?

Comment: "You" don't get "flagged". Your question gets put on on hold, closed, and deleted. And it will be, because personal advice had been collectively decided to be off topic at some point in the past.

Comment: Thanks. Where could I ask the question then?

Comment: I haven't got the slightest idea.

Comment: We don't know anything about you, but the best place to direct these questions are to math teachers/instructors/professors who you know, and who know you. At the very least, a math teacher (for example) should be able to put you in touch with someone more knowledgeable and vaguely in your area.

Comment: I think [academia.se](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) would be the closest match for a place to ask such a question on stackexchange. However, the question should ask for general advice, rather than be about the specifics of your situation.

Comment: @Thomas Can it be still specific to mathematics?

Comment: @Miksu Any answers you would get would be 1) basically fortune-telling, because we do not have    information and can't predict your future well, and 2) not terribly useful for many other readers and 3) would be answers to a question that isn't about mathematics. These are the main reasons, as I see them, that we don't handle such questions. It is just unreasonable to expect that strangers on the internet can substitute for people who know you academically IRL.

Comment: Okay, I guess I won't ask the question.

Comment: Do ask the question, but not here. Ask your teachers. Starting may be from the most senior ones whose courses you have taken. They can give you an opinion and/or refer you to someone else. They may be unable to judge your chances if you haven't taken advanced courses yet. In that case they will probably tell you exactly that.